# how to customize payment method in abantecart

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, open-source

I am new to abantecart. i need help with customising the payment method. On clicking on the checkout on the cart page, i'd like to go to a page with a form which the user should fill some payment information (this serves as the payment method). Then an email should be sent to the store owner for approval and when approved an email should be sent to the user on the approval status. Please how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best to create new payment is using of [AbanteCart Developer Tools](https://github.com/abantecart/developer_tools_extension).
Just download pack, unpack some of subdirectories (for v.1.2.9 and you should use "1.3" folder) in to your "extensions" directory, then go to admin and install it. Then generate new project with extension type "payment".
You can look into default_pp_standart extension and use it as example to create your custom payment form.